# android.database.sqlite.SqlException : No such Table (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

My App was working perfectly by fetching records from sqlite database , but suddenly it is giving me no such table , sqlite exception.
Please help me figure it out the problem.

SqliteListHelper2.java

```
public class SqliteDatabaseHelper2 {
    DbListHelper2 helper2;

    public SqliteDatabaseHelper2(Context context) {
        helper2 = new DbListHelper2(context);
    }

    public SqliteDatabaseHelper2 open(Context context) throws SQLException {
        helper2 = new DbListHelper2(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db2 = helper2.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        if (helper2 != null) {
            helper2.close();
        }
    }

    public long insertData2(String artworkImage, String wrapperType, String 
            artistName, String collectionName,
            String trackName, String collectionPrice, String trackId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db2 = helper2.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DbListHelper2.ARTWORK_IMAGE, artworkImage);
        values.put(DbListHelper2.WRAPPER_TYPE, wrapperType);
        values.put(DbListHelper2.ARTIST_NAME, artistName);
        values.put(DbListHelper2.COLLECTION_NAME, collectionName);
        values.put(DbListHelper2.TRACK_NAME, trackName);
        values.put(DbListHelper2.COLLECTION_PRICE, collectionPrice);
        values.put(DbListHelper2.TRACK_ID, trackId);
        long id2 = db2.insert(DbListHelper2.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        return id2;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData2() {

        SQLiteDatabase db2 = helper2.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = { DbListHelper2.UID, DbListHelper2.ARTWORK_IMAGE, 
                DbListHelper2.WRAPPER_TYPE,
                DbListHelper2.ARTIST_NAME, DbListHelper2.COLLECTION_NAME, 
                DbListHelper2.TRACK_NAME,
                DbListHelper2.COLLECTION_PRICE, DbListHelper2.TRACK_ID };
        Cursor cursor2 = db2.query(DbListHelper2.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, 
        null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
            int index = cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.UID);
            int cid = cursor2.getInt(index);
            int index0 = 
            cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.ARTWORK_IMAGE);
            String cid0 = cursor2.getString(index0);
            int index1 = cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.WRAPPER_TYPE);
            String cid1 = cursor2.getString(index1);
            int index2 = cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.ARTIST_NAME);
            String cid2 = cursor2.getString(index2);
            int index3 = 
            cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.COLLECTION_NAME);
            String cid3 = cursor2.getString(index3);
            int index4 = cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.TRACK_NAME);
            String cid4 = cursor2.getString(index4);
            int index5 = 
            cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.COLLECTION_PRICE);
            String cid5 = cursor2.getString(index5);
            int index6 = cursor2.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper2.TRACK_ID);
            String cid6 = cursor2.getString(index6);

            buffer.append(cid + " " + cid0 + " " + cid1 + " " + cid2 + " " + 
                     cid3 + " " + cid4 + " " + cid5 + " "
                    + cid6 + "\n");

        }
        return cursor2;
    }

    static class DbListHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Tracks";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "SingleTrackList";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private Context context;
        static final String UID = "_id";
        static final String ARTWORK_IMAGE = "artworkUrl100";
        static final String WRAPPER_TYPE = "Wrapper_Type";
        static final String ARTIST_NAME = "artistName";
        static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "collectionName";
        static final String TRACK_NAME = "trackName";
        static final String COLLECTION_PRICE = "collectionPrice";
        static final String TRACK_ID = "trackId";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "Create table " 
                +TABLE_NAME+" (" +UID
                +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ARTWORK_IMAGE+" 
                VARCHAR(500), "+WRAPPER_TYPE
                +" VARCHAR(50), "+ARTIST_NAME+ " VARCHAR(500), 
                "+COLLECTION_NAME+" VARCHAR(500), "
                +TRACK_NAME+" VARCHAR(500), "+COLLECTION_PRICE+" 
                VARCHAR(500), "+TRACK_ID
                +" VARCHAR(255))";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE = "Drop table If Exists " 
       +TABLE_NAME;

        public DbListHelper2(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            Message.message(context, "Constructor called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db2) {
            try {
                Message.message(context, "onCreate called");
                db2.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Message.message(context, "onCreate failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db2, int oldVersion, int 
            newVersion) {
            try {
                Message.message(context, "onUpgrage called");
                db2.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db2);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

SingleTuneDetails.java : This is the class in which i am inserting json data into my sqlite database.

```
public class SingleTunesDetails extends Activity {
private SqliteDatabaseHelper2 listHelper2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
listHelper2 = new SqliteDatabaseHelper2(getBaseContext());

listHelper2.open(getBaseContext());
url = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=" + passedData7;
    // Calling async task to get json
new GetSingleTrackDetails().execute();
}

class GetSingleTrackDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private JSONObject jsonObj;
    private Cursor cursor;
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                tracks = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = tracks.getJSONObject(i);

                    artworkImage = c.getString("artworkUrl100");
                    wrapperType = c.getString("wrapperType");
                    artistName = c.getString("artistName");
                    collectionName = c.getString("collectionName");
                    trackName = c.getString("trackName");
                    collectionPrice = c.getString("collectionPrice");
                    trackId = c.getString("trackId");

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> tunesMap = new HashMap<String,  
                    String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    // contact.put(TAG_ID, firstname);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_ARTWORK_IMAGE, artworkImage);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_WRAPPER_TYPE, wrapperType);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_ARTIST_NAME, artistName);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_COLLECTION_NAME, collectionName);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_TRACK_NAME, trackName);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_COLLECTION_PRICE, collectionPrice);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_TRACK_ID, trackId);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    singleTrackDetails.add(tunesMap);

                    long id = listHelper2.insertData2(artworkImage, 
                              wrapperType, artistName, collectionName,
                             trackName, collectionPrice, trackId);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
        cursor = listHelper2.getAllData2();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
            wrapperTypeText.setText(passedData2);
            artistNameText.setText(passedData3);
            collectionNameText.setText(passedData4);
            trackNameText.setText(passedData5);
            collectionPriceText.setText(passedData6);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    listHelper2.close();
}
```

}

Logcat :

05-19 12:40:37.996: E/SQLiteLog(3236): (1) no such table: SingleTrackList
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236): Error inserting trackId=879273565 trackName=Better Together Wrapper_Type=track artistName=Jack Johnson artworkUrl100=http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/pf/us/r30/Music4/v4/41/df/6f/41df6fb5-d08f-5573-fb4b-a56a9b6ea0cb/UMG_cvrart_00602537868858_01_RGB72_900x810_06UMGIM25847.100x100-75.jpg collectionName=In Between Dreams collectionPrice=9.99
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: SingleTrackList (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SingleTrackList(trackId,trackName,Wrapper_Type,artistName,artworkUrl100,collectionName,collectionPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:909)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:520)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1523)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1395)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at com.example.fasoostest.SqliteDatabaseHelper2.insertData2(SqliteDatabaseHelper2.java:41)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at com.example.fasoostest.SingleTunesDetails$GetSingleTrackDetails.doInBackground(SingleTunesDetails.java:135)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at com.example.fasoostest.SingleTunesDetails$GetSingleTrackDetails.doInBackground(SingleTunesDetails.java:1)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-19 12:40:38.016: E/SQLiteDatabase(3236):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
05-19 12:40:38.021: E/SQLiteLog(3236): (1) no such table: SingleTrackList
05-19 12:40:38.021: W/dalvikvm(3236): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d47a08)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: SingleTrackList (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, artworkUrl100, Wrapper_Type, artistName, collectionName, trackName, collectionPrice, trackId FROM SingleTrackList
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:909)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:520)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:65)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1370)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1217)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1088)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1256)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.example.fasoostest.SqliteDatabaseHelper2.getAllData2(SqliteDatabaseHelper2.java:51)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.example.fasoostest.SingleTunesDetails$GetSingleTrackDetails.onPostExecute(SingleTunesDetails.java:154)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.example.fasoostest.SingleTunesDetails$GetSingleTrackDetails.onPostExecute(SingleTunesDetails.java:1)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
05-19 12:40:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you created any database table?

Comment: sir in my app ,i have two tables one to display listview and other table is this , my first table isnt giving me any error but my second table is giving me sqlite exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have two tables one to display listview and other table is this , my first table isnt giving me any error but my second table is giving me sqlite exception

The code you posted shows only one table being created.

Use only one `SQLiteOpenHelper` per database file. The second helper just discovers that the database file already exists and has the correct version, and therefore the `onCreate()`/`onUpgrade()` lifecycle callbacks don't need to get invoked. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Just put the SQL that creates both tables in the same `onCreate()` as two separate `execSQL()` calls.

Also consider removing any `catch` blocks in your helper `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()`. Syntax problems *need*  to be thrown upwards.

There's also a whitespace issue that results in "no such column" discovered by M D in his deleted answer.

Comment: Sir thanx alot , your explanation really helped me , it worked , thanx for taking out some time to explain me what to do